# How to handle missing fields in a HIVE table?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have an interesting question.

I created a hive table as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE LEARN001(
     Name STRING,
     Location ARRAY<STRING>,
     PesonalDetails STRUCT<sex:STRING,age:INT>,
     FatherSonDetails MAP<STRING,INT>
     )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
    COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY ','
    MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY ':';
```

and I'm providing the inputs as:

```
anupam|Delhi,mumbai,chennai|Male,45|Daulat:4

cathy|California,San Fransisco, Canada|Sam:2

load data inpath '//LEARN111.txt' into table LEARN001;

select * from LEARN001;
```

I'm getting output as:

```
anupam  ["Delhi","mumbai","chennai"]    {"sex":"Male","age":45} {"Daulat":4}                                                                         
cathy   ["California","San Fransisco"," Canada"] {"sex":"Sam:2","age":null}  NULL
```

However, the output Im expecting is:

```
anupam  ["Delhi","mumbai","chennai"]    {"sex":"Male","age":45} {"Daulat":4}   
cathy   ["California","San Fransisco"," Canada"] {null,null} {"Sam":2}
```

Is there any provision to tweak this code to get the desired output?
Can we assign null values if the fields are missing in the record?

Comment: `{null, null}`is not a valid map or struct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand that when you create a Hive table pointing to a delimited file, it considers the position of the values separated by your delimiter in your file as value for your columns. In short, you have "positional parameters" declared in your hive table to refer to the data on your file. So when you have a record like shown below

```
cathy|California,San Fransisco, Canada|Sam:2
```

This is associated to your schema as shown below

```
Name STRING - cathy
Location ARRAY<STRING> - California,San Fransisco, Canada
PesonalDetails STRUCT<sex:STRING,age:INT> - Sam:2
FatherSonDetails MAP<STRING,INT> - NOTHING
```

And when you fire a `select *` statement, your results for columns are displayed, obviously, as shown above.

This record rather qualifies as a bad record according to your schema definition and that is why addition of an extra `|` solves your proeblem.

Hope that explains the process.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to explicitly add that missing column in the data

```
Canada||Sam:2
```

In which case you would more likely get `{"sex":null,"age":null}`

HIve is trying to read 4 fields, but only sees three columns, so your 4th is NULL and the data at the end will be forced into the third field  however it can

Comment: yeah that would work , but I just wanted to know if it was possible programatically . Thanks for your explanation :) .

Comment: Programmatically? Sure. Parse the data using Spark, then do validation checks against the columns. Insert a valid Struct into Hive